# Woocommerce product details can be added or removed and shows up in checkout page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html, woocommerce

This is my [website](http://customvapeclouds.com/product/10-ml-bottle/). The problem is that if you click "add to cart" without selecting anything from the dropdowns, your checkout page will display [like this](http://postimg.org/image/gtztipgw1/).

How do I go about fixing this issue? I want users to be able to add details to the products like [how this website](http://e-liquid-recipes.com/create) is doing it. Only the flavours they choose and the selections they choose from dropdown should show in checkout page as well as in the order.

I do have some programming / node.js experience so I can deal with some level technicality.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I would suggest go for this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/, there you can add custom fields ( like select boxes ) and you can set them as mandatory fields, the selected option will be carried over to cart, checkout, order and email as well.

Comment: Thanks but how do I make this plugin so that users can click 'add flavour" and a new flavour select and concentration select box comes up?

Comment: Ah, that `Add Flavour` that some thing needs custom code, I doubt any plugins exist, can be done with little jQuery.